# SslHandler and 'An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine'?

Tags: netty

I am writing a SSL server using netty, following the Secure Chat example.

I have automated tests that

1. open a ssl connection
2. communicate back and forth for a while
3. close the channel

(ie the client closes the channel when it is done)

The tests all pass, I have another handler in my pipeline that implements 'exceptionCaught'.
Sometimes, when the client closes the channel this generates an ExceptionCaught event on the server with

```
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
   at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
   at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
   at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:218)
   at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:186)
   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:359)
   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:66)
   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:364)
   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:238)
   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:38)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

By adding a simple logging downstream handler both above and below the SSLHandler, I have determined that the SSLHandler seems to be generating a downstream write event after the client closes the channel, but I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Any pointers on what is going on here?